# Newer Debian versions of python3 on older Debian distros?

Tags: linux, debian, python

I would like to be able to use python3.3+ as well as the `python3-bson-ext` package on `Wheezy`. By default, `Wheezy` has 3.2 available, and does not have the `python3-bson-ext` package. But `testing` does. Is there an easy recipe for pulling just those two packages from `testing`?

I have my own repository for our local packages, is there a way I could place snapshots of those two packages in that repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `apt-pinning`, which allows you to cherry pick packages from different versions of the distro, while keeping things generally as they are.

An old but useful quick introduction can be found [here (jaqque.sbih.org)](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html)

Answer (score 1):

The testing package `python3-bson-ext` depends on python >=3.4~ and the python3 package actually is 3.4.1-1.

You can download the debs from testing and install then with `dpkg -i`, but you may run into dependency problems.

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-bson-ext

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3